# .NET Core Data Protection API Chosen-Plaintext-Attack (CPA)

Tags: asp.net, encryption, .net-core

I'm using the .NET data protection API in ASP.NET Core with the default settings to encrypt URL parameters. I think this uses a symmetric algorithm but not sure.

I'd like to know as I'm a bit concerned about a KPA/CPA attack on the URL parameters.

I'm configuring like this:

```
services.AddDataProtection();
```

And consuming like this:

```
public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public SomeService(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
    {
        _dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(nameof(SomeService));
    }

    public string SomeServiceFunction(string text)
    {
        // What algorithm is used here?
        return _dataProtector.Protect(text);
    }
}
```

What algorithm does this use?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **cryptography or security flaws** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The question is really about what algorithm is used in the default data protection API. Once I know that I can probably figure out whether it's vulnerable to CPA myself. I'll rephrase.